# Allow either password or private key SSH authentication

Tags: linux, security, ssh

I set the lines `PasswordAuthentication yes` and `PubkeyAuthentication yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. I also disabled root login for security purposes. I can now SSH with a user's password without specifying my private key. However I am now unable to deploy over ssh to my server from a script because I would need to specify the password. Therefore I would like the option to ssh into my server without a password by just specifying the private key. However I am always being asked for the password, even if I pass the private key to the `-i` option. How can I set this up?

Please note that this is not a passphrase associated with the private key, but rather the password associated with the user. It's the password created with the `passwd` command.

Comment: Please look in your log file, obviously you have something misconfigured.

Comment: @NickW Can you please explain?

Comment: If it is a passwordless private key, you will not get a password prompt, unless you either 1. created a private key with a password or 2. have wrong permissions on a file, or put a carriage return in the public key, or one of many things the log will tell you about quite quickly.

Comment: @NickW I really don't think it's the passphrase attached to the private key but rather the password that is associated with the user account. It's the password that was created by running the `passwd` command.

Comment: When you used ssh-keygen, did you put a password in? If not, just look at /var/log/secure (or the log for sshd on your system) it will have a fairly descriptive error message.

Comment: @NickW the key was created by Amazon Web Services. I don't think they put a passphrase in it.

Comment: Alright, after a quick glance through their documentation it seems to be passwordless. Now log into your server and check that log file out, it will tell you exactly why it doesn't like the private key.

Comment: @NickW I think John below figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the SSH key isn't passphrase locked, the most likely problem is permissions on the destination user's ~/.ssh directory or ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (or ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2) file. I usually set those 600 and 644 respectively, and things work for me.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is it. The `.ssh` folder is actually only in the `root` user's home and not in the user's home that I'm using for SSH. The `.ssh` folder has 700 right now so that would explain the password. Would you recommend changing it to 777 since I disabled root ssh, or should I instead change the owner of the directory to the new user and make it 700?

Comment: If you're going to log in as a user, that user needs to have a .ssh/ directory, and an authorized_keys file with the permissions that John suggested. The authorized keys file needs to contain the contents of the public part of the key.

Comment: @NickW Ok so I can just copy the `authorized_keys` file from the root directory?

Comment: Yeah, just chown it to the new user, and chmod it 644.

Comment: NEVER set ~/.ssh or any contents to 777. That's bad juju. You should have a /root/.ssh directory and a /root/.ssh/authorized_keys file - if SSH'ing as root works, copy the authorized_keys file to /home/$USER/.ssh/, make sure the permissions are the same, and you should be good to go.

Comment: @John I think that if you 777 anything in the ssh directory you will get no end of errors from sshd.

Comment: @John Yeah I realized that right after I said that, it was a bad idea haha

Comment: This worked for me, but I needed 700 and 644 respectively. (the directory needed +x)